# Proving relation between canonical structures

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been asked to prove that $f_*\left(\bigcup\mathcal{A}\right)=\bigcup f_{**}\mathcal{A}$, where $f:X\to Y$ and $\mathcal{A}\in \mathcal{P}X$ (subscript * represents image maps). This is quite trivial in the standard way to prove the equivalence of sets (showing they are subsets of eachother), but I'm wondering if there's any way we can prove this from the fact that $f_*:\mathcal{P}X\to\mathcal{P}Y$ and $\bigcup:\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}X\to\mathcal{P}X$ are canonical functions in the sense that they are defined naturally for any power set and the power set of a power set. It's probably just an ungrounded "gut feeling", but I'm just curious if it's possible. And in general, are there any cases where we use the fact that certain canonical operations exist to prove new results? Enlighten me

Comment: No, naturality does not imply this. However it does follow from the fact that direct image is the left adjoint of inverse image.

Comment: Can you be specific in what you mean? The course I'm in doesn't use the same terminology